# Delphi - Связать 2 главных таблицы и 1 подчинённую

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

Имеется 3 таблицы: `Студенты`, `Ведомость`, `Предметы`.
Таблица `Ведомость` подчинена таблицам `Студенты` и `Предметы`.
Я знаю, как связать 2 таблицы через компонент `table` : через `mastersource`. Но чтобы связать 3 таблицы, как я понимаю, нужно уже использовать компонент `Query`. Связать нужно так, чтобы на форме было несколько связанных гридов, где в главных гридах выбираются поля, а в подчинённом гриде отображается результат на основе 2-х главных гридов, и всё это ещё желательно редактировать прямо в гриде.

Comment: К сожалению, в текущей формулировке на Ваш не возможно дать лаконичный ответ. Всё зависит от задачи. Например. Просто вывод данных для просмотра в одной таблице (читайте DBGrid), преставление данных в режиме master-detail или совместное редактирование данных в нескольких таблицах. В каждом конкретном случае решение будет отличаться. Поэтому, уточните постановку задачи.

Comment: Исправил - Связать нужно для отображения в Grid и редактирования

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно разделить задачи отображения и редактирования.

С задачей отображения можно справиться силами одного `Query`, у которого в свойстве `SQL` прописан соответствующий запрос с `INNER JOIN`.

Задача редактирования несколько сложнее. С помощью, опять же, единственного `Query` можно отображать актуальные данные. При определённых условиях для этого можно воспользоваться даже тем же самым `Query`, что служит для отображения. Для внесения изменений лучше воспользоваться `Command` с запросами `INSERT`, `DELETE` или `UPDATE` (в зависимости от задачи).

Однако в любом случае для редактирования придётся писать код, так как `Query` не подставляет автоматически данные в связанные поля и поэтому самостоятельно не может корректно отредактировать набор данных из нескольких связанных таблиц.

> всё это ещё нужно редактировать прямо в гриде

Это крайне сложно осуществить. По крайней мере с помощью стандартных компонентов из коробки. Хотя бы потому что:

- Как уже сказано выше, `Query` сам не поймёт что и куда нужно добавлять в случае внешних ключей;
- Стандартный `DBGrid`обладает очень скромным функционалом. Максимум, что можно от него добиться - сделать **простой** выпадающий **текстовый** список через `PickList`.

Но, можно попробовать подобрать другие, более функциональные, компоненты. Например, от EhLib.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос